# Add image to D3.js Sunburst Example

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I would like to extend this D3.js sunburst example in the way that it can display images rather than text. http://www.jasondavies.com/coffee-wheel/

[image]

The interesting part of the js example code is following:

```
d3.json("wheel.json", function(error, json) {
  var nodes = partition.nodes({children: json});

  var path = vis.selectAll("path").data(nodes);
  path.enter().append("path")
      .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "path-" + i; })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      .style("fill", colour)
      .on("click", click);

  var text = vis.selectAll("text").data(nodes);
  var textEnter = text.enter().append("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return brightness(d3.rgb(colour(d))) < 125 ? "#eee" : "#000";
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return x(d.x + d.dx / 2) > Math.PI ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .attr("dy", ".2em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var multiline = (d.name || "").split(" ").length > 1,
            angle = x(d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90,
            rotate = angle + (multiline ? -.5 : 0);
        return "rotate(" + rotate + ")translate(" + (y(d.y) + padding) + ")rotate(" + (angle > 90 ? -180 : 0) + ")";
      })
      .on("click", click);
  textEnter.append("tspan")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .text(function(d) { return d.depth ? d.name.split(" ")[0] : ""; });
  textEnter.append("tspan")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.depth ? d.name.split(" ")[1] || "" : ""; });
```

The question is how I can replace the text with an image in this scenario.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You would need to append `image` elements instead of `text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var image = vis.selectAll("image").data(nodes);
var imageEnter = image.enter().append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
  .attr("width", 16)
  .attr("height", 16)
  .attr("x", function (d) { 
    return 33; // calculate x 
  }).attr("y", function (d) {
    return 33; // calculate y 
  });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image

force-directed images and labels: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642